# Running Jmeter and Selenium in sequence from Blazemeter using taurus framwork

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter, taurus

Running Jmeter and Selenium in sequence from Blazemeter using taurus framwork
i tried to use sequence, it doesnt help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZE9Mh.png)

I wan to run first jmeter file and then like to execute for some actions  to clean up things.

Answer (score 0):

We are not telepathic enough to guess what's wrong without seeing your full YAML file.

The [Startup Schedule](https://gettaurus.org/docs/ExecutionSettings/#Startup-Schedule) setting controls how [`execution` blocks](https://gettaurus.org/docs/ExecutionSettings/#Execution-Settings) are being processed.

So if you have JMeter and Selenium in separate `executions` - the setting should work.

If they're in a single execution you will have to make them sequential using different means, i.e. [tearDown Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) and [WebDriver Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mixing-selenium-into-your-load-scenario) in JMeter.

Comment: modules:
  nose:
    ignore-unknown-actions: true
  local:
    sequential: true

execution:    
- executor: jmeter
  iterations: 10
  scenario: test
  concurrency: 10
  ramp-up: 30s
  hold-for: 1m
  

- executor: selenium
  scenario: test02
  hold-for: 3m

  capabilities: 
    browserName: chrome


scenarios:
    
 test:
    script:
           test.jmx
 test02:
    generate-f......